# How can I make the bar labels in a PGf plot multi-line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I've got the following simple chart in my document:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
enlargelimits=0.15,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ylabel={\# of Respondents},
symbolic x coords={Short label,A longer label,A quite long label that should be two lines,Another long label I want to multiline},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords align={vertical},
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
]
\addplot coordinates {(Short label,1) (A longer label,151)
(A quite long label that should be two lines,19) (Another long label I want to multiline,14)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Those last two labels are currently almost doubling the size of the chart, and there's plenty of room to have them each be two shorter lines under the corresponding column. Is there any way to do so? I've tried inserting `\\` but it had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `x tick label style` to:

```
    x tick label style={font=\small, rotate=45, anchor=north east, 
                        text width=10em, inner sep=2pt, align=right},
```

[image]

However, try to make labels shorter ...

Comment: Huh. That did it, but it's still leaving space around the figure as if there aren't any line breaks: any idea how to adjust that as well?

Comment: @David, what space around figure? If you insert tikzpicture in `fbox` and add option ˙\draw` to `x tick label style`, you will see that around picture is only small space.. It can be a bit reduced by better estimation of nedeed `text width` for tick labels (for examples, instead of `10em` set `9.3em`. One way is to enable that the longest text can be in three lines.  Or I didn't understood your comment well. Anyway, if you have new problem, please ask new question.